# Is using php_sapi_name() to detect CLI reliable?

Tags: php, security

How reliable is it to detect if a PHP script is invoked at the command line as a matter of API security?

We have a series of PHP scripts that (in production) will be served over HTTP - the client will use cURL - but we will have occasion to run the same scripts at the command line.

Our security for each endpoint requires a new signature with each call (based on shared secret and other request args hashed into a signature string). It's a PITA to create the hash when calling the endpoint via the CLI.

Assuming anybody who can log onto the server is allowed to run the script without a token and signature, is it secure to use `php_sapi_name()` to entirely bypass our authentication scheme? e.g.:

```
if(php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    //skip authentication; let the script run
}
```

Or could this somehow be exploited if you are not in fact logged into the server and running the script via CLI?

Comment: While it's probably safe, I don't think you should expose command line scripts to the web, why not keep those scripts outside of the web directory?

Comment: Replay the following statement in your mind "is it secure to [...] entirely bypass our authentication scheme?"

Comment: @Devon - these would be the same scripts that are normally called over HTTPS - but on occasion would be executed at the CLI.

Comment: Sounds like your logic should be extracted to a separate function or class that can be included in both a console script and a web script.

Comment: @Sammitch - if a user is SSH'ed into a server, presumably they are already authenticated; I am asking if there is ever a scenario that `php_sapi_name()` could have a value of 'cli' outside of the situation where an a user is authenticated via SSH on the server and calling the script from the command line on that server.

Comment: @Devon - agreed - it would be in a function and included in the header of every script that is accessible via the web server. I do want to clarify that there is just one script - it resides within the web directory and is accessible via both HTTPS and CLI.

Comment: That's not what I meant.  The same script should not exist for both contexts, write two separate scripts, that call the same function.  One script can live in the web directory and authenticate through the web, one script can live outside the web directory and have execute permissions at the system level.

Comment: @Devon - Yes, I had considered that...and it is a pragmatic approach, but I still wonder if `php_sapi_name() == 'cli'` is able to be exploited...

Comment: Why even wonder?  Even if it can't be exploited right now, what's to say that an exploit or a server configuration change couldn't cause your web server to read as cli in the future?  It's just unwise even if it can't be exploited now.

Comment: @Devon - Fair point, I suppose. Seems from the other thread that you linked to that the best practice is to be conservative in this regard...